# NameError: undefined method `xyz' for class `State' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

In model:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :country

  alias_method :abc, :xyz

  def self.xyz

  end
end
```

In log:

```
1.9.3-p551 :005 > State.abc
NameError: undefined method 'xyz' for class 'State'
```

I am new to `alias_method` in rails. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Rails, `alias_method` is part of ruby itself, [which you really should learn](http://ruby-doc.org/) before trying to use Rails.

Your problem here is that you've defined `xyz` as a class/singleton method, but `alias_method` called as you've done works on instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
class State
  def self.xyz
    ap 'inside'
  end

   self.singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :abc, :xyz)
end
```

Following should work :

```
>> State.xyz
>> State.abc
```